# Does Quickly support GTK3?

Tags: gtk, application-development, quickly, pygtk

Simple question: can [Quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly) use GTK2 only or also GTK3 for GUI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**As of 12.04**
Gtk3 is the default on 12.04.

**For 11.x**
Simple answer: **No, it does not** (Quickly 11.10).

Extended answer:
Since all the code produced by quickly can be edited, you can change it to support gtk3, but it does not come with support.

There is however a [branch of quickly](https://code.launchpad.net/~quickly-committers/quickly/gtk3-projects) in development that (only) supports gtk3. You can see the difference in the templates: some have `from gi import ...` (which is needed for gtk3) and the older templates have `import gtk` (which does not work with gtk3).

You should be able to uninstall your current quickly version and get the gtk3-enabled version with:

```
bzr branch lp:~quickly-committers/quickly/gtk3-projects
```

I have however not tried it and it is of course not the current stable version of quickly (which has lots of implications...)

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 11.10 uses Gnome3/GTK3 by default, as well as Unity, so yes, it supports GTK3 :)

I see that you've added a pygtk tag to your question. You should consider dropping it in favor of GObject Introspection, as g-i and PyGTK are not compatible anymore. It's an easy transition though, and g-i provides many other tools as well. PyGTK is not going to be developed any more either, so sooner or later, you are going to have to make the switch. There will never be a GTK3 version of PyGTK.

Comment: The use of GTK3 in 11.10 does not mean that automatically GTK3 is supported, because you can use GTK2 at the same time. And quickly is using PyGTK (which seems to be obsolete) and Glade

Comment: PyGTK is not obsolete. It's supported. It just won't be developed any further because there's no longer any need for it. And you can use g-i with Quickly, although the ubuntu-application template uses PyGTK (and g-i, actually, but that's fixed now) by default. Changing from PyGTK to g-i is not a huge issue though.

Comment: Can you please provide a link where I can more info about g-i tutorials like code example etc

Comment: Here is a good list of examples. You'll be happy to see that the differences that big, since PyGTK have been close to GTK all along: http://www.learngtk.org/pygobject-tutorial/examples/